# How do I get the hanging chest in Yakushi Village?

Tags: okamiden

In the middle of Yakushi Village, there's a treasure chest on a hanging platform suspended by ropes. An invisible wall prevents me from jumping towards it and my power slash doesn't work on the ropes.

How do I get the hanging treasure chest in Yakushi Village?

[image: Hanging treasure chest]

Comment: Not sure about the specifics, but later in the game a bridge to it should appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you convince enough people to move to Yakushi Village, a bridge will be built that lets you reach the floating island.

[image: A bridge connecting the floating island]

Comment: how many people is "enough"?

Comment: @Gnemlock I wasn’t keeping count unfortunately. I got the bridge around when you team up with Kagu for the 2nd time, after you unlock quick travel.